# Stripping extraneous chars from gchats pulled via imap with Python

Tags: python, regex, gmail, imap

I'm working on a project that pulls down chat transcripts from gmail via imap. I have successfully logged in, and displayed the most recent gchat transcript via the following code:

```
import getpass, imaplib, email, re, sys

s=imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com', 993)
getuser = raw_input("<username>")
getpass = raw_input("<password>")
s.login(getuser, getpass)

s.select('[Gmail]/Chats',readonly=True)

result, data = s.uid('search', None, "ALL")#fetch email body (RFC822) for the given ID
latest_email_uid = data[0].split()[-1]
result, data = s.uid('fetch', latest_email_uid, '(RFC822)')
raw_email = data[0][1]
print raw_email

s.close()
s.logout()
```

The output involves a whole lot of gobbledygook that I want to get rid of. For example, this is a single line of chat:

```
<con:conversation xmlns:con="google:archive:conversation"><cli:message
to="<email redacted>" from="<email redacted>"
int:cid="13865109981248781158" int:sequence-no="4"
int:time-stamp="1323547231442" xmlns:cli="jabber:client"
xmlns:int="google:internal"><cli:body>uhh</cli:body>
```

Ideally I'd like to keep the "to=" field, as well as everything between cli:body /cli:body tags. I've been reading through stack for examples of this, as well as of regex, but I'm a newbie and I'm getting confused. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at XML parsing libraries. A fast library for python is [lxml](http://lxml.de/):

> The lxml XML toolkit is a Pythonic binding for the C libraries libxml2 and libxslt. It is unique in that it combines the speed and XML feature completeness of these libraries with the simplicity of a native Python API, mostly compatible but superior to the well-known ElementTree API.

Then extract the `to` attribute and the text of the `cli:body` element via [XPath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) expressions for example.

Note: If you have never worked with XML or XML libraries before, give yourself some time to learn. XML is not the easiest thing to master, but applying the right model for the problem will make your code much cleaner, I suppose.

Comment: I will take a look at it. It seems surprising that there is no way to do this just within python - I say this because I'm worried about beginning to wrestle with another language on a short timespan (doing this for an assignment due next week - obviously I've bit off a bit more than I can chew :/). However, I really appreciate the answer and will read through it. Thanks!

Comment: @spikem, Didn't want to scare you off, the resulting XML handling will probably be only four lines of code (wanted to try this myself, but your code didn't work for me instantly). Besides, Python has some XML handling built-in (see: [xml.dom.minidom](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.dom.minidom.html)). Anyway, good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use an XML parser for this. Python has many XML parsers to choose from (both inside and outside of the Python Standard Library). Documentation for the XML packages in the Standard Library are found in [Structured Markup Processing Tools](http://docs.python.org/library/markup.html).

Below is an example using [xml.etree.ElementTree](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html). In it I made some assumptions about your XML (since you did not provide a complete tree). The example takes in only a single `message` element and its children, but this should get you started in figuring out how to deal with the entire `conversation` tree.

```
from xml.etree.ElementTree import ElementTree
import StringIO

# This is all set up to have data for the example.
msg = """<cli:message to="to@nowhere.com" from="from@nowhere.com"
int:cid="13865109981248781158" int:sequence-no="4" int:time-stamp="1323547231442"
xmlns:cli="jabber:client" xmlns:int="google:internal">
  <cli:body>uhh</cli:body>
</cli:message>"""
msgf = StringIO.StringIO(msg)

# Now we parse the tree given a file-like object.
tree = ElementTree()
tree.parse(msgf)
to = tree.getroot().attrib['to']
body = tree.find('{jabber:client}body').text
```

Now we have:

```
>>> to
'to@nowhere.com'

>>> body
'uhh'
```

Comment: [Sorry, unfamiliar with stack's commenting system, accidentally submitted, typing more now, stand by]
Okay let's see if I've got this:
msg is declaring what is in the message. 

msgf is turning it into a string

tree is parsing the msgf string in xml hierarchy (?)

"to" is looking for the specific "to" attribute that was declared up in "msg" and "body" is doing the same. 

So now I have to figure out how to declare all of the fields involved, and apply it for all chats coming in.

Thanks for your help!